# Workaround for Fragment URLs not allowed with Google Redirect URI

Tags: apache, .htaccess, express, angular-ui-router, passport.js

I use mac to develop a MEAN stack project. My web pages `https://localhost:3000/#/login` and `https://localhost:3000/#/new` work (note that all my pages need to have `/#/` in the middle to work). `https://localhost:3000/#/new` has a button that leads to a google login by `passportjs`. In my `routes ==> index.js` I set

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
... ...

router.get('/auth/google', passport.authenticate('google', { scope: ['profile', 'email'] }));
router.get('/auth/google/callback',
  passport.authenticate('google', { successRedirect: '/login',
                                    failureRedirect: '/login' }));
```

In `Google APIs ==> Credentials`, when I set `https://localhost:3000/auth/google/callback` as `Authorized redirect URIs`. Clicking on the login button on my page returns an error

```
Error: redirect_uri_mismatch

The redirect URI in the request, https://localhost:3000/auth/facebook/callback, does not match the ones authorized for the OAuth client. Visit https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials/oauthclient/367100934152-7csfhcdnkapil4obku1pr2cnrsmthk61.apps.googleusercontent.com?project=367100934152 to update the authorized redirect URIs.
```

I guess it is because `https://localhost:3000/auth/facebook/callback` is not a valid URI for my app, but if I set `https://localhost:3000/#/auth/facebook/callback` in the setting page, it is NOT allowed: `Invalid Redirect: https://localhost:3000/#/auth/google/callback cannot contain a fragment.`

So, does anyone know if I could modify my app to work without `#`, so that `https://localhost:3000/login` and `https://localhost:3000/new`, etc. will work? As a result, `https://localhost:3000/auth/facebook/callback` will be a valid URI too...

**Edit 1:**

Following the answer of @Sevran and the doc [how to configure your server to work with html5mode](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-configure-your-server-to-work-with-html5mode), I did the following:

1) added `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true)` in `app.config`

2) added `<base href="/" />` in `index.ejs` (note I don't have `index.html` in the project)

3) keeps `.state('new', url: '/new', ...` in `app.config`

4) did NOTHING in `httpd-vhosts.conf`, which has `<VirtualHost *:80>` and `<VirtualHost *:433>`, because I think my server is controlled by `express.js` rather than `httpd-vhosts.conf`, and the port is `3000`.

5) did NOT add `.htaccess` in the project like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17909743/702977)

6) added in `app.js` the following, I also tried to change `index.html` to `index.ejs`.

```
app.use('/js', express.static(__dirname + '/js'));
app.use('/dist', express.static(__dirname + '/../dist'));
app.use('/css', express.static(__dirname + '/css'));
app.use('/partials', express.static(__dirname + '/partials'));

app.all('/*', function(req, res, next) {
    // Just send the index.html for other files to support HTML5Mode
    res.sendFile('index.html', { root: __dirname });
});
```

The tests shows

1. entering `https://localhost:3000/#/new` in the URL bar becomes `https://localhost:3000/new`, and it loads the corresponding page.
2. entering `https://localhost:3000/new` in the URL bar raises a `not found 404` error.
3. entering `https://localhost:3000/auth/google` in the URL bar raises the `Error: redirect_uri_mismatch` as above.

To conclude, I think the rewriting (of a url without `#`) should be managed by express, but the code I posted did not do the job. Regarding `.htaccess`, I tried also to put it in the `DocumentRoot` of `httpd-vhosts.conf` or the root folder of the project, it did not help.

Comment: Are you using angularjs for front-end ?

Comment: Yes, I use mean stack: angularjs for front-end...

Comment: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-configure-your-server-to-work-with-html5mode, check this link, you have to set the virtual host and point the directory to root folder of the application.

Answer (score 1):

In app->init.js enable below mode in config

```
 $locationProvider.html5Mode({
      enabled: true,
      requireBase: false
    }).hashPrefix('!');
```

Comment: I did this, then `https://localhost:3000/#/new` becomes `https://localhost:3000/#%2Fnew` and shows a blank page; `https://localhost:3000/new` raises a `Not found 404` error.

Comment: href should be like this href="/#!/new"

Comment: I changed `.state('new', { url: '/new', ... }` to `.state('new', { url: '/#!/new', ...}`, it is still the same thing...

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the hash from your URL using the HTML5 mode:

```
appModule.config(['$locationProvider', function($locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}]);
```

Don't forget to set the base in your **`<head>` tag**:

```
<head>
    <base href="/">
    ...
</head>
```

---

Note that if you are using **Angular 1.6**, you also need to change the `hashPrefix`:

```
appModule.config(['$locationProvider', function($locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    $locationProvider.hashPrefix(''); // remove the ! from URL
}]);
```

More info about the changelog **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41226167/4927984)**.

Comment: This is almost what I did in `Edit 1`, right? I added `$locationProvider.hashPrefix('')`, but the problem is still there...

Answer (score 1):

The changes you have to make:

**1) Angular Side:** as you already changed

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true) in app.config

added <base href="/" /> in index.ejs

keeps .state('new', url: '/new', ... in app.config
```

2) **hta access**

```
RewriteEngine   On
RewriteBase     /
RewriteCond     %{REQUEST_URI} !^(/index\.php|/img|/js|/css|/robots\.txt|/favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond     %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond     %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule     ./index.html [L]
```

**3) This change you need from server side,**

**If using apache:**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName my-app

    DocumentRoot /path/to/app

    <Directory /path/to/app>
        RewriteEngine on

        # Don't rewrite files or directories
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
        RewriteRule ^ - [L]

        # Rewrite everything else to index.html to allow html5 state links
        RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

In the above `my-app` will be the application name. and `DocumentRoot` and `Directory` paths should be **complete path to your application root**

**For Express:**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use('/js', express.static(__dirname + '/js'));
app.use('/dist', express.static(__dirname + '/../dist'));
app.use('/css', express.static(__dirname + '/css'));
app.use('/partials', express.static(__dirname + '/partials'));

app.all('/*', function(req, res, next) {
    // Just send the index.html for other files to support HTML5Mode
    res.sendFile('index.html', { root: __dirname });
});

app.listen(3006); //the port you want to use
```

[Here is the Documentation regarding it](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-configure-your-server-to-work-with-html5mode)

Comment: I'm testing it... i think if I do the necessary for `express`, the configuration in `apache` is not necessary, right? neither the `.htaccess`?

Comment: yes, `.htaccess` change is not required, I am not much aware if `.htaccess`, make change in `apache`, I think it will serve your purpose

Comment: change either `express` or `apache` not both. Also, you should create a new `hosts` file, and enable it.

Comment: you mean I should create another `httpd-vhosts.conf`?

Comment: yes, create a new conf file, and enable it using sites-enable feature

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139486/discussion-between-sravan-and-softtimur).